# Eclipse RCP no icons in plugin.xml extensions

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-luna

Switched my Eclipse from Kepler to Luna, and I have this weird bug in the `plugin.xml` of my RCP app.

Although all the views have icons, the icons don't show anymore in the `org.eclipse.ui.views` tree. Is this because RCP 3.8 is deprecated in Luna?

[image]

Comment: I don't think anything has been deprecated. I see this too, looking at the code it seems to still be trying to find the icons but something is going wrong. So my guess is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

No. You may don't have some plugin. That plugin files is in the Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers(http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-rcp-and-rap-developers/lunasr2) plugin folder. You can force merge that plugin folder to your eclipse plugin folder.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.